# Duplicate title tags on non crawl pages

Tags: seo, page-title, robots.txt

favorite
This question already has an answer here:
Duplicate title tags in Google Webmaster Tools 1 answer
I have set up my robot.txt file so that google doesn't crawl limit pages (how many products show on a page) so it doesnt class all these pages as duplicate content.

[image]

However when i go onto html improvement on webmaster i can see under duplicate title tags it has still referenced some of my limit pages, not all of them only some.

[image]

So it is telling me i have duplicate title tags on these pages when Google shouldn't even be able to see them, how can i fix this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google will remember previously indexed pages.
Once it scans your site and gets an updated robots.txt you will have the option of requesting removal of the indexed pages.

Here is information on removing webpages in Google Webmaster Tools
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en

Once removed it should disappear from your duplicate title tags list.